# Subquery in fluentPDO

Tags: php, mysql, fluentpdo

I'm trying to "translate" this query into a fluentPDO statement but i can't find a way to use subqueries with it

```
SELECT plan.*, COUNT(DISTINCT click.id) AS clicks, COUNT(DISTINCT impression.id) as impressions, IFNULL(A.earnings, 0) AS earnings FROM plan
LEFT JOIN click ON click.plan_id = plan.id
LEFT JOIN impression ON impression.plan_id = plan.id
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT plan_id AS earnings_id, SUM(signup.earning) as earnings FROM signup
) A ON A.earnings_id = plan.id
GROUP BY plan.id
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a nicer way than just putting your raw SQL subquery in the leftJoin method:

```
$fluent->from('plan')
->select('COUNT(DISTINCT click.id) AS clicks, COUNT(DISTINCT impression.id) as impressions, IFNULL(A.earnings, 0) AS earnings')
->leftJoin('click ON click.plan_id = plan.id')
->leftJoin('impression ON impression.plan_id = plan.id')
->leftJoin('(SELECT plan_id AS earnings_id, SUM(signup.earning) as earnings FROM signup) A ON A.earnings_id = plan.id')
->groupBy('plan.id');
```

I find [SitePoints's FluentPDO guide](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-code-html-email-newsletters/) quite useful, but they don't mention subqueries. They also suggest that you don't need to explicitly left join click to plan and impression to plan, but in practice, I can never tell which way FluentPDO will infer the relationship between two tables.